# MongoDb Data Localization in .net c# for both querying and displaying

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have this collection let us say 'Location' as below:

```
public class Location : BaseDocument
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

before i was using external json files per class to translate labels and data it self and i can add as many languages as i want and it worked like a charm.

but then i faced a problem when user tries to search for a `Location` in Arabic for example giving that the stored name is in English and there was my approach dead end!

**First Approach**

i though about adding a 2-Dimensional array for each translatable collection which contains a pair of language and it's localized text that way i can display and search for documents in both languages

so my class will look like this

```
public class Location : BaseDocument
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string[][] LocalizedTags { get;set; }
}
```

and therefore my stored document will look like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId('12312332132'),
  "Name": "Abandoned Warehouse AX-2",
  "LocalizedTags" : [
    "EN" : "abandoned",
    "EN" : "warehouse",
    "AR" : "مهجور",
    "AR" : "مستودع",
   ]
}
```

**Second Approach**

or should i keep using my external translation json files for displaying purpose and just merge tags for querying purposes? something like this:

```
public class Location : BaseDocument
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string QueryableText {get;set;}
}
```

and my stored document...

```
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId('12312332132'),
      "Name": "Abandoned Warehouse AX-2",
      "QueryableText" : "abandoned;warehouse;مهجور;مستودع"
    }
```

and keep my local translation json files

```
location.en.json
{
  "abandoned" : "abandoned",
  "warehouse" : "warehouse"
}
location.ar.json
{
  "abandoned" : "مهجور",
  "warehouse" : "مستودع"
}
```

so, which approach is better performance-wise ? i like second one because first i get to separate translation externally and minimize document complexity 
i still need an advice from you guys 'which approach is better performance-wise' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well..after digging deep

it depends on the app actually

1- If the app is multi-organization then app should store translations in the database (First approach)

2- If the app is specific for one organization then app has a better approach storing the translations in separate local files (Second approach)